# Py2Exe openpyxl importerror

Tags: python, error-handling, executable, py2exe, openpyxl

I have a python application that depends on openpyxl and works well when running it through the python interpreter. However, when creating an exe with py2exe. The exe was generated but when I click on it I get an error and the following log is generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "excelTest.py", line 1, in <module>
File "openpyxl\__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>
File "openpyxl\workbook\__init__.pyc", line 5, in <module>
File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.pyc", line 16, in <module>
File "openpyxl\writer\write_only.pyc", line 23, in <module>
File "openpyxl\writer\excel.pyc", line 36, in <module>
File "openpyxl\packaging\extended.pyc", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name __version__
```

Could anyone let me know what the problem is and how I can fix it. 
Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(windows=['excelTest.py'], options={"py2exe": {"includes": ["openpyxl","os","ntpath","Tkinter","tkFileDialog","sys"]}})
```

Comment: openpyxl does not support py2exe

Comment: @CharlieClark on another machine I generate a working executable with py2exe and openpyxl. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

First, I tried the proposed solution of downgrading to 2.3, but I use read-only functions that didn't work.

Then, reading some openpyxl forums I found that the problem is that 2.4 uses a Jason file for the configuration. But I couldn't instruct py2exe to include it and use it.

Finally, I used pyInstaller, and it worked at the first try.

Answer (score 11):

The issue is because __version__ is read from .constants.json file and it is not being taken up by py2exe. For work around, I edited the library file openpyxl\packaging\extended.py

```
#from openpyxl import __version__
__version__ = "2.4.5"
```

I commented the import and created a variable __version__ with the version text from .constants.json file present in openpyxl library. Again created the executable using py2exe.

Worked fine for me.

Comment: Worked for me also.

Comment: Yep, this is it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem using openpyxl 2.4.3 . I found that to create a .exe file you have to revert to an older version of openpyxl. To do so:

1. Open the command prompt and uninstall openpyxl with 'pip uninstall openpyxl'
2. Reinstall openpyxl using an older version 'pip install openpyxl==2.3.5'

Answer (score -1):

In openpyxl\packaging\extended.py add it at line 5:

```
__version__ = str(__version__)
```