# Building an executable file for python code using py2exe. ImportError: No module named cell

Tags: python, module, cell, py2exe, openpyxl

I installed "py2exe" for "Python2.7" , made a "Hello World" program, used py2exe to build its exe and it worked perfectly.

Now when I tried building the exe of my actual code, the folders get created and exe is also created without any problem but when I launch the exe the console appears for less than a second and closes.

Following are import commands which I am using:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
__version__='2.4.8'
from openpyxl import __version__
from openpyxl import Workbook
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
```

My setup file is like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
__version__='2.3.5'
from openpyxl import __version__
from openpyxl.cell import Cell

setup(
    windows=[{"script":'try.py'}],
    options = {"py2exe":{"includes":["tweepy","openpyxl.reader.excel","openpyxl.cell","openpyxl.workbook","openpyxl.worksheet","jdcal","xlutils","json","xlrd","Tkconstants","Tkinter","tkFileDialog","xml.etree.ElementPath", "xml.etree.ElementTree","xml.etree.cElementTree"],
 "packages": ["xml.etree", "xml"]}}
    )
```

The error which I am getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\__init__.pyc", line 29, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\workbook\__init__.pyc", line 5, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\__init__.pyc", line 4, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.pyc", line 23, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\utils\__init__.pyc", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cell
```

My file name is try.py

Comment: please show the line number 8 from the try.py file.

Comment: from openpyxl import Workbook -- is the line 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Py2Exe openpyxl importerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411621/py2exe-openpyxl-importerror)

Comment: @CharlieClark sir in this post you have commented that openpyxl dose not support py2exe . Can you please elaborate that and explain why and how

Comment: openpyxl only supports distribution of itself as a library using `pip, `py2exe` is not `pip`.

Comment: so any remedial for that ? What can be the best to do in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is too use **pip**, just write in your terminal:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

If you are using windows, press:

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Type `CMD` in the run window which has opened

and then:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

for the future, sometimes (very often) you need to install python packages, for that reason pip is your best friend.

Comment: I have already installed that. My code is running  without any error from the python shell.  This error, I am facing, is when I am converting it too .exe file

Comment: maybe you are using different python, check which python is in your terminal. I mean the default python.

Comment: Python 2.7.13 is the version.

Comment: are you using linux?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is with `openpyxl\utils\__init__.py` that imports `.cell`, i.e. `openpyxl\utils\cell.py` which is not included in your application.

In your `setup.py` you listed some of the openpyxl subpackages in option `include`:

```
options = {"py2exe":{"includes":["tweepy","openpyxl.reader.excel","openpyxl.cell","openpyxl.workbook","openpyxl.worksheet",…
```

And openpyxl has [a lot of subpackages](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/0f8537998f95c9d8d44913c2edb367516b799d4a/openpyxl/?at=default).

You have to list `openpyxl` in packages:

```
setup(
    …
    options = {"py2exe":{
        "packages": ["openpyxl", "xml.etree", "xml"]}}
    )
```

No sure about listing all subpackages. If the `packages` above don't help try
listing them all:

```
setup(
    …
    options = {"py2exe":{
        "packages": ["openpyxl", "openpyxl.workbook", etc…, "xml.etree", "xml"]}}
    )
```

Comment: Try `packages`, not `include`. I updated my answer. `include` is for individual modules.

Comment: I have done this also. Still the same error. Is there any other means through which I can convert my file into an exe file.

Comment: cx_Freeze, PyInstaller.

Comment: I dont want to switch to another converter takes alot of time to again read and understand. Is there nothing that I can change in my py2exe one ??